# Time consuming conversion from pivot table to flat table

Tags: java, mysql, pivot, dynamic-data, pivot-table

In our application, we have to process more than 300k records using a table, whose structure will be something similar as pivot table.

```
 CREATE TABLE properties (
   id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   item_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   property_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   value VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But the query to make a flat table i.e. (converting rows to columns), is itself taking more than 15 seconds.The query is

```
 SELECT
     item_id,
     MAX(IF(property_name = 'feildName1', value, NULL)) AS feildName1,
     MAX(IF(property_name = 'feildName2', value, NULL)) AS feildName2,
     MAX(IF(property_name = 'feildName3', value, NULL)) AS feildName3,
     MAX(IF(property_name = 'feildName4', value, NULL)) AS feildName4,
     MAX(IF(property_name = 'feildName5', value, NULL)) AS feildName5
  FROM
  properties as p
  GROUP BY
  item_id;
```

My requirement is i have a form, which will have dynamic fields. To handle the dynamic fields i am taking approach of conversion of rows into columns as follows ->

Table having values in pivot form -

```
      ID |  ITEM_ID |   PROPERTY_NAME   | VALUE        |
      -------------------------------------------------
      1  |     1    |   feildName1      |  kepl1       | 
      2  |     1    |   feildName2      |  exit1       |  
      3  |     1    |   feildName3      |  interview1  |
```

Flat table

```
      ITEM_ID |  feildName1 |   feildName2 | feildName3 |
      ---------------------------------------------------
      |     1 |   kepl1     |  exit1       | interview1 |
```

So ultimately the search query will be on Flat table. But the conversion from pivot table to flat table is taking more than 15 seconds.